# What configuration properties must be set when configuring a MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource (Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, jndi

I want to create a `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource`, but I am not sure which setter methods (`setURL`, `setPort,` `setPropertiesViaRef`, etc) are optional and which are required when configuring the `DataSource` object. Do I need to configure all of those methods, or only a few of them?

Comment: Please make sure that you should actually need to use this, contrary to its name, a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` in JDBC is **not** a connection pool. It is a data source **for** a connection pool as provided by most Java EE servers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry, just for clarification: `ConnectionPoolDataSource` does not create a data source for a database that uses a connection pool?

Comment: No, it is used to create `PooledConnection` objects that can be held in a connection pool, it is not a connection pool itself. The actual data source providing the connection pool is - usually - built in the Java EE server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the configuration you would like to set however, the following parameters should be sufficient in most of the cases:

```
MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource poolDataSource = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
poolDataSource.setUser("yourUsername");
poolDataSource.setPassword("yourPassword");
poolDataSource.setServerName("yourServersIP");
poolDataSource.setPort(3306);
poolDataSource.setDatabaseName("yourDBName");
```